# Is it a good idea to log all sql queries in django production?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7

I am thinking of logging all the sql queries made to our postgresql database for every request by using a middleware like 
[Snippet 1](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/290/)
or
[Snippet 2](https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/264/)

Will it affect the performance of application ? Postgres normal logging doesn't work for me, because along with the sql query I also have to store some additional information.

I tried logging all the sql queries by using database logging, but sadly that doesn't seem to work when DEBUG=False in settings file.

Comment: We don't know your setup, so we can not tell what will happen. Certainly it won't speed up the app. ;-)

Comment: @KrzysztofSzularz but I want to know , is it a good idea? To do database logging in django level ? Is it a good practise ?

Comment: Good practice is to not store DB queries in logs in production. It may cause to credentials/sensitive information leak. Also @KrzysztofSzularz is right. It will slow the app. Also will have unnecessary logs, you might miss out important logs in between those

Comment: @ruddra I didn't tell it will slow down the app. I said it won't speed it up.

Comment: @ruddra I also fail to see how one can miss out on "logs in between" when using some sane logging aggregation solution.

Comment: Having said that, I would not do it myself on production.

Comment: Worth noticing that postgres itself stores a log of transactions made to it. I personally would prefer logging database access on database level.

Answer (score 3):

you can have a custom logging by define Logging in setting.py
please read this document.

it is possible to logging when debug=false with this doc:

[logging doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging/#configuring-logging)
add this code to setting.py:

```
LOGGING = {
'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False,
'handlers': {
    'file': {
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
        'filename': '/path/to/debug.log',
    },

},
'loggers': {
    'django.db.backends': {
        'handlers': ['file'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}}
```

in two links that you put above in snippet2 says that it works only when debug=true
and in snippet1 in line 35 there is a condition like this :

```
if len(connection.queries) > 0 and settings.DEBUG:
    ....
```

that shows it works in debug=true

I hope it helps.